# _CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES error with architecture i386

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am working to rotate a sprite that is attached to a CPbody.
I am using this code

```
[shape->data setRotation:(float) CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES( -body->a )];
```

When I run this code I get this error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES", referenced from:
      _updateShape in GamePlay.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any ideas on why this is happening, Iv worked for a while trying to get around this and can't

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You are not linking in Cocos2d for the i386 architecture. You could check which frameworks you are linking within your project.

Have you used the cocos2d template to create the project in the first place?

Can your app run on the device instead of the simulator?